# android:Test Class not found in eclipse

Tags: robotium

I am running Junit test with Robotium frame work in eclipse,also I have added the robotium-solo-3.1.jar in lib folder still getting error as Test Class not found in selected project, please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just import the jar into the libs directory of the test project and then adding it to the Build Path Libraries:

> Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libreries -> Add JARs... -> Project/libs/robotium-solo-3.1.jar

Answer (score 3):

your tests name should start with the word test

```
public void testClickOnButton() throws Exception {
}



public void testLogin() throws Exception {
}
```

Comment: and no one in the world ever mentioned that. :|

Answer (score 2):

Why do you use a so old version? Current version is robotium-solo-5.0.1.jar

I suggest to use this one!

Answer (score 0):

use current version which is robotium-solo-5.0.1.jar right now. if you are using eclipse add to your add to your build path or add it your lib folder of project